# Ionic/Angular class member vs method

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a ionic 3 template and corresponding typescript class

In the template I have

```
<p>{{welcomeMessage}}</p>
```

In the class I have

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
   selector: 'page-my-test',
   templateUrl: 'my-test.html',
})
export class MyTestPage {
   public welcomeMessage = "Hello World";
}
```

In another template I have

```
<p>{{getWelcomeMessage()}}</p>
```

In the class I have

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
   selector: 'page-my-test',
   templateUrl: 'my-test.html',
})
export class MyTestPage {
   public getWelcomeMessage() {return  "Hello World";}
}
```

Performance wise which will benefit more? Keeping Class level members or methods that return some data

Comment: Using getWelcomeMessage is one useless step added because angular need to run the function instead of taking directly the value, and you write more code. Using getter is useful in term of code organisation only, I don't see any benefit there.

Comment: Methods may be called more than once.

Comment: I understood that the class member were used to store state and methods would perform operations on those state, does this mean we can have tons of class members saving data that may or may not be HTML bound or are in any kind a state.